# How can I retrieve a value from Firebase database/Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, firebase

[image]

I have a Firebase database that contains Ethereum addresses for a whitelist. I'm a beginner, I just started with fireBase. I've done a lot of research and I got stuck. I would retrieve all the addresses inside the database and store them in an array using usestate in React JS.

Thank you very much

Comment: Have you checked [Get all documents from a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection) part of the documentation?

Comment: Yes, I checked it but I got a bunch of errors...any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
import { useState } from "react";

const [state,setState] = useState([]) 

const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "nameOfYourCollection"));
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  setState(prevState=>[...prevState,doc.data()])
});
```

Comment: I got a lot of errors: collection, getDocs were not found in 'firebase/firestore', db not defined...(I have firebase/firestore installed)

Answer (score 1):

If you have errors that say *collection, getDocs, db not defined...* try to import this with '@'.

I mean:

`import { collection, getDocs } from "@firebase/firestore"`

`import { db } from "@lib/firebase"`